# Add activity class from subprojects in android

Tags: android, qt5

I am building an android project using Qt.
The project consists of several subprojects which handle specific functions.
The subproject do not have android files because the android related files like manifest.xml, gradle files etc are part of the main project and so is the android/src dir.

Is there a way that I can use an activity java class defined in the subprojects without having to place them in the main project?

Thanks

---- Edit ----
All submodules are libs that are included in the main application. So when I try to create templates for them, I get the message "No application .pro file found" in the template wizard. To create the android templates, I have to first change the qmake template field to app, then generate the android template and then change the field back to lib.

Comment: Not familiar with Qt, are projects included as sub-modules? if so, you can just add a manifest to each submodule, manifest files are merged together at buildtime, so you can define different activities in different modules. However, only one activity should have the action main and laucher category. (you may even have more than one xml per module without Android Studio complaining). In your manifest file, at the bottom, there is a tab that says "Merged Manifest" check to see there are no conflicts there.

Comment: Thanks @alexm for the reply. Somehiw the merging is ot working. I suspect that qt is considering only the main manifest and ignoring the subproject one. I was abke to confirm this by using same class names in the activities. Ideally it should say conflicting class names, but it didn't.